# How to Put a Comma in the Number Element of Webform?

Tags: webforms

how can I put a comma in a number element in drupal 8 webform to show in a view? For example, amounts like 1,000.00. Thanks.

Comment: Does the field setttings in your view not give you the option? Are you using the [Webform Views Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) module?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2290029

The problem is not actually with Drupal or Webform, it's a limitation of the HTML5 number field.